# Inserting MySQL results from PHP into JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to make a very simple autocomplete function on a private website using a trie in JavaScript. Problem is the examples I have seen and trying are just using a predefined list in a JavaScript array.

e.g. `var arrayObjects = ["Dog","Cat","House","Mouse"];`

What I want to do is retrieve MySQL results using PHP and put them into a JavaScript array.

This is what I have so far for the PHP (the JavaScript is fine just need to populate the array):

```
<?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('SERVER', 'U/NAME', 'P/WORD', 'DB');
    if (!$mysqli)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT category.name FROM category")) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
    }   
while($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
     printf("%s, ", $name); 
    }
?>
```

Then I want to insert essentially each value using something like mysql_fetch_array ($name); (I know this is incorrect but just to show you guys what's going on in my head)

```
<script> -- this is the javascript part
(function() {
    <?php while $stmt=mysql_fetch_array($name))
     {
       ?>
        var arrayObjects = [<?php stmt($name) ?>];
    <?php } 
       ?>
```

I can retrieve the results echoing out fine, I can manipulate the trie fine without MYSQL results, I just can't put them together.

Comment: Consider using Ajax calls and passing data in JSON format instead of this cross-language madness that you have now

Comment: Thanks, not that I'm afraid of something new just a fair bit to learn with Ajax calls and passing JSON, I could have easily used an autocomplete function straight from the net but I thought I would have a go at it myself seeing as I did Red Black and Radix Tress in uni years ago but they were all java, self taught PHP so was just sticking with what I know. The cross language madness is only in my head ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, what you're doing is looping through your result array, and each time you're printing out the line `var arrayObjects = [<?php stmt($name) ?>];`. However this doesn't convert between the PHP array you're getting as a result, and a javascript array.

Since you started doing it this way, you can do:

```
<?php
    //bind to $name
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT category.name FROM category")) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
    }
    //put all of the resulting names into a PHP array
    $result_array = Array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result_array[] = $name;
    }
    //convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
    $json_array = json_encode($result_array);
?>

<script>
    //now put it into the javascript
    var arrayObjects = <?php echo $json_array; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Worked! Brilliant! Thanks heaps mate. I had already dabbled a few attempts putting results into a PHP array, just didn't know there was a conversion function to put into JSON and pass to javascript! Great example.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic--this makes everything possible!

Answer (score 5):

Use `json_encode` to turn your PHP array into a valid javascript object. For example, if you've got the results from your database in a php array called `$array`:

```
var obj = "<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>";
```

You can now use `obj` in your javascript code

Comment: Why in quotes? Then you will need to JSON.parse the obj

Answer (score 0):

For the auto-completion you can use the [`<datalist>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp). This is a relatively new feature in HTML5 ([see support table](http://caniuse.com/datalist)) but the [polyfill](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/Relevant-Dropdowns) exists.
Fill the `<option>` tags in php when building the page and you a are done.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I was after for this, good to know for future reference.