# How to store MySQL date in Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have searched over the Internet, there is a lot of way to store MySQL records into Javascript array though PHP, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248728/inserting-mysql-results-from-php-into-javascript-array). However I can't really store the date record in Javascript.

Let say,

My MySQL date record rows in column called holiday_date: 2017-06-25, 2017-06-26, 2017-06-27.

How can I store in Javascript after I converted them into json by

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT public_holiday.holiday_date 
            FROM public_holiday";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result_array = Array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         $result_array[] = $row;
    }

    $json_array = json_encode($result_array);

    echo $json_array;
  ?>
```

?

I have tried to store them into a javascript date array like

```
var holidays = [<?php //sample array for example 
        $loop_one = true;
        foreach ($result_array as $date) 
        {
            if ($loop_one) 
            {
                echo "'new Date(\'$date\')'";
                $loop_one=false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo ", 'new Date(\'$date\')'";
            }
        }
?>];
```

but all of these are invalid.

I need your help, much appreciated.

Comment: When you say invalid, which exact code blows up?

Comment: What is `javascript` code do you excpected?

Comment: the var holidays = [<?php echo "new Date(".$json_array.")"; ?>];
var holidays = <?php echo $json_array; ?>; are invalid... the php part doesnt have problem

Comment: I expect to store all the date record into javascript date array...like normal array: var holidays = [new Date("2017-06-26"), new Date("2017-06-27") ...], but I don't know how to store from the MySQL

Comment: eval($json_array), loop through it and transform the values into Date, store these in a new array.

Comment: @Capsule I don't understand, could you please provide more information?

Comment: Try my below answer @YashidaKimLeeRoger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a javaScript date object array you need to change your script code only no need to change the PHP code.
You can use **JSON.parse** and **forEach** loop.

**Try like this**

```
<script>
    var holidays = '<?php  echo $json_array;?>';
    holidays=JSON.parse(holidays);
    var holidayArray=[];
    holidays.forEach(function (key) {
        holidayArray.push(new Date(key));
    });
    console.log(holidays);
    console.log(holidayArray);
</script>
```

It will produce an out put as

[image]

I thing it will help you.

Comment: TQ SO MUCH! YOU JUST SAVED MY LIFE!

Answer (score 1):

So in your sample, the `$result_array` variable will be a PHP array like:

```
$result_array = ['2017-06-25', '2017-06-26', '2017-06-27'];
```

You do not really need to convert this to JSON before passing it to your Javascript.  Instead, you could print those string values directly into your Javascript to instantiate the date object, i.e.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT holiday_date FROM public_holiday";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result_array = Array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $result_array[] = $row['holiday_date'];  # Return the actual date value and not an array
}
?>
```

Javascript Part:

```
var holidays = [<?php 
    $firstLoop = true;
    foreach ($result_array as $date_result) {
        # Here you could format your $date_result variable as a specific datetime format if needed to make it compatible with Javascripts Date class.
        if ($firstLoop) {
            $firstLoop = false;
            echo "new Date('$date_result')";
        } else {
            echo ", new Date('$date_result')";
        }
    }
?>];
```

In this example, I'm constructing a javascript array of `new Date($phpDateTime)` objects.

Comment: Do you have any demo? Since this solution does not work in my browser.

Comment: @YashidaKimLeeRoger I don't have a demo available, but I noticed a bug in your code in the body of the `while($row ...)` and have amended that into my answer.  If you have further problems can you provide some example of the resulting javascript.  This would indicate where it's rendering the dates incorrectly.

Comment: My browser shows me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < after I insert your solution into the javascript. By the way, what kind of bug does my `while ($row...)` have?

Comment: did you need this arrray ["new Date('2017-06-25')", "new Date('2017-06-26')", "new Date('2017-06-27')"]   ????? is it ? @YashidaKimLeeRoger

Comment: @JYoThI yes! yes! from MySQL to javascript array!

Comment: The error in the while loop was that you were assigning the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc` which is an associative array.  So instead of an array of date values ["2016-06-25", "etc", "etc"], you had an array of key/value pairs such as: [["holiday_date" => "2016-06-25], ["holiday_date" => "etc"]].  I have made a small amend to the Javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while loop` should be like this and push the `date` into new array

```
<?php

$result_array = Array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $result_array[] = $row['public_holiday.holiday_dat'];
}

 //$result_array contains date like this $result_array = ['2017-06-26', '2017-06-27'];

?>
```

**Javascript exampl**e

```
<script>

    var holidays = [<?php $result_array = ['2017-06-26', '2017-06-27']; //sample array for example 
    $loop_one = true;
    foreach ($result_array as $date) {

        if ($loop_one) {
            echo "'new Date(\'$date\')'";

            $loop_one=false;
        } else {
            echo ", 'new Date(\'$date\')'";
        }
    }
?>];

 console.log(holidays);

</script>
```

**Update 1:** Finally your code should be like this

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT public_holiday.holiday_date FROM public_holiday";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result_array = Array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $result_array[] = $row['public_holiday.holiday_dat'];
    }

?>
<script>

    var holidays = [<?php
    $loop_one = true;
    foreach ($result_array as $date) {

        if ($loop_one) {
            echo "'new Date(\'$date\')'";

            $loop_one=false;
        } else {
            echo ", 'new Date(\'$date\')'";
        }
    }
?>];

 console.log(holidays);

</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the ` var holidays = [<?php $result_array = ['2017-06-26', '2017-06-27']; //sample array for example ` what do you mean?

Comment: Supposedly the record of data fetch from MySql, but you hard coded it?

Comment: My browser is still showing me the unexpected  Unexpected token <

Comment: you need to ignore this line in your code $result_array = ['2017-06-26', '2017-06-27'];

Comment: My browser keeps showing me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string, and it is not working!

Comment: I tested in my local it's works . i think you missed something . just try copy paste my answer and execute once for testing purpose @YashidaKimLeeRoger

Comment: Is there any possible to store the mysql date into javascript date array?

Comment: I am not sure because my browser just keeps showing me the unexpected caught token <. I don't even know whether it is running or stopped.

Comment: i think you have some syntax error . just update your post with updated code . i will try to debug it @YashidaKimLeeRoger

Comment: please update entire page code . your given part of code is fine . @YashidaKimLeeRoger

Comment: You said your code is working, can you show me yours? Because my full code is considered confidential, I can't just post it online.

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick .it's useful for future user reference @YashidaKimLeeRoger